# How to delete an adview from UI?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent, admob

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kfis.png)

I wanted to add ads in my app. Firstly I tried mopub view (fabric) to show my add but lately I have used AdMob to for showing ads. I have deleted all the mopub codes and admob is showing the ad correctly. But there is a adview (as you can see in the picture- image title at the top) is showing above the admob view. How can I delete it?

here  is my activity_main.xml file.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"

android:layout_width="match_parent"

android:layout_height="match_parent">



<!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" />
</LinearLayout>

<!-- Listview to display slider menu -->

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
    android:layout_width="270dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@drawable/sidebar_gradient"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@color/white_60_per_trans"
    android:dividerHeight="0.5dp" />
```

Comment: Are you sure you posted the correct layout file? It does not seem to fit to the image.

Comment: @H Add view can Hide you are doing to remove this cant possible if you want Hide Add this is simple Add.setvisible(View.Gone);

Answer (score 0):

try with this way

```
 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    android:visibility="gone"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" />
```

programmatically

```
adView.setvisibility(View.GONE);
adView.setvisibility(View.ENABLE);
```